# C Array Insertion/Deletion

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

For an [array](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/), it shows that Insertion and Deletion are `0(n)`:

[image]

Two questions related to this:

- What does this consider as an "insertion" or "deletion" operation? For example, would the following be an insertion?

  ```
  int numbers[10];
  numbers[4] = 12; // this would be 0(1) though (?)
  ```
- Is this referring to a dynamic array where an insert/delete implies that there is some resizing involved in the list? That is, if we have a 10-number array and we want to remove element 4, instead of doing `numbers[3] = 0`, it implies we want to get an array of size 9 where the previous entry was the item at the fifth position? For example something like:

  ```
  int numbers2[9];
  memcpy(numbers2, numbers, sizeof(int) * 3);
  memcpy(numbers2+3, numbers+4, sizeof(int) * 6);
  ```

Comment: Your example isn't *inserting* a new element, it's *overwriting* an existing one.

Comment: Be careful of taking those complexities too seriously -- they are correct, as conventionally defined, but some are apples and some oranges. For example, insertion into an array is defined as insertion at an index, but insertion into a *linked list* is defined as insertion *after a cursor*. If you have to insert into a linked list at an index, and you don't have a cursor to the insertion position already, you have to search for it first, which is Θ(n). This is why it's important to understand how to calculate them and where they come from, instead of just memorizing a table of formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding or removing a element from an array means you need to shift the existing elements up or down to account for the added or removed element.

For example:

```
// assumes the array has capacity to add a member
void add_array(int *arr, int len, int index, int value)
{
    int i;
    for (i=len-1; i>index; i--) {
        arr[i+1] =  arr[i];
    }
    arry[index] = value;
}

void remove_array(int *arr, int len, int index)
{
    int i;
    for (i=index; i<len-1; i++) {
        arr[i] =  arr[i+1];
    }
}
```

This is O(n) because on average it will take *n* iterations to perform the necessary shifting.